# Failing to receive data from UART in DMA mode

Tags: stm32, stm32f4, nucleo, cubemx, stm32cubeide

I am trying to receive 8 bytes from my pc on my NUCLEO F446RE stm32 board.
Transmitting to the pc works.
The problem is, I am unable to receive data using DMA.
I saw an example with almost the same code and it has worked for the person.
If I use the interrupt mode (just change HAL_UART_Receive_DMA to HAL_UART_Receive_IT, it does work and the RX Complete callback is being called.

Here is the complete main.c. DMA is in circular mode.

```
main.c
```

https://pastebin.com/1W4BCjxB

Comment: Somehow, this code does work:
https://github.com/MYaqoobEmbedded/STM32-Tutorials/blob/master/Tutorial%2040%20-%20UART%20DMA/UART_DMA_main.c

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got it solved, it is actually ridiculous.

So, this is part of the code that CubeMX generates:

```
MX_GPIO_Init();
MX_USART2_UART_Init();
MX_DMA_Init();
```

If I order it as follows:

```
MX_GPIO_Init();
MX_DMA_Init();
MX_USART2_UART_Init();
```

It works!!!

Comment: Interrestingly, it is only a problem when using CubeMX integrated in STM32CUBEIDE. Stand alon CubeMX works great.

Comment: Thanks, same problem here. Saved me some debugging time.

Comment: It looks like a bug in the integrated STM32CUBEIDE or I am missing something. I get a grey MX_DMA_Init line and I am not able to step it up so that it remains above USART2. I had to click in "Do Not Generate Function Call" and call it myself in user code before the USART2 initialization.

Comment: +1 I was upset that this bug had cost me over an hour of my life debugging. Exasperated, I turned to my colleague and ranted about this problem. Turns out an issue he's been trying to figure out for over a day is caused by the same problem!

Comment: Lost 1/2 day to find this issue. Is this a problem with CUBE MX?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Here is the solution with using the CubeMX integrated view.
In the [CubeMX->Project Manager->Advanced Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3v4ln.png) you can select the order of functions to be generated. I moved my MX_DMA_Init to the top to ensure that the DMA is ready before any other peripherals are initialised.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized the DMA variables as well as handler for the DMA interrupt. You will need to do something along these lines

Initialize DMA:

```
hdma_usart2_rx.Instance = DMA2_Stream1;
hdma_usart2_rx.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_2;
hdma_usart2_rx.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
hdma_usart2_rx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
hdma_usart2_rx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_DISABLE;
hdma_usart2_rx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
hdma_usart2_rx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
hdma_usart2_rx.Init.Mode = DMA_CIRCULAR;
hdma_usart2_rx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_HIGH;
hdma_usart2_rx.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_usart2_rx);
```

```
void DMA2_Stream2_IRQHandler(void)
{
    HAL_NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(DMA2_Stream2_IRQn);
    HAL_DMA_IRQHandler(&hdma_usart1_rx);
}
```

`HAL_UART_Receive_DMA` only starts the DMA and does not handle the interrupt and the data transfer.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I saw these lines in the generated file stm32f4xx_hal_msp.c inside function HAL_UART_MspInit.
I forced to run this function in main and now when sending "xyz" I only get the 'z'.

But, as I said, this code works:
https://github.com/MYaqoobEmbedded/STM32-Tutorials/blob/master/Tutorial%2040%20-%20UART%20DMA/UART_DMA_main.c
Still did not find the vital difference.

Comment: HAL_UART_Init calls that function, so it is set.

Comment: But, that only initializes the UART. right? Your DMA hasn't been configured yet.

Comment: Hmm, but how does it work when I copy code from github?

Comment: Here is the function. It does initialize DMA.
https://pastebin.com/JUcTdhj9

Comment: Are you sending just a single instance of xyz?

Comment: Check my answer. It was one instance.

Comment: That makes sense. The data must have been coming in before the DMA initialized. So, you missed x and y.

Comment: It gave me a headache. Well, I'm gonna use only the stand alone CubeMX now.